# Finite group with prime index maximal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ the largest prime that divides the order of $G$. Suppose that all the maximal subgroups of $G$ have a prime index. Then, the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal in $G$. Furthermore, there is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order exactly $p$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$: I managed to show that the $p$-subgroup of Sylow $P$ is normal in G. For the second part, I thought to consider a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ contained in $P$, and show that $N$ has order $p$. But I don't know how to get out of here. It is possible to show that $N$ is elementary abelian, since $N'\trianglelefteq G$ and $N \leq P$ is solvable.

Comment: This is Huppert's theorem (see M. Hall The theory of groups, Theorem 10.5.8).

Answer (score 1):

On the contaray assume that $N_{G}(P)\ne G$, hence there exists a maximal subgroup $M$, where $P\le N_{G}(P)\le M<G$. By the assumption, $|G:M|=q$ and since $P\le M$, $q<p$. Now $|G:N_{G}(P)|=q|M:N_{G}(P)|$. Note that $|M:N_{G}(P)|$ equals the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $M$. Hence we have $|M:N_{G}(P)| \equiv 1 \mod p$. On the other hand $|G:N_{G}(P)|\equiv 1 \mod p$. Remark that $|G:N_{G}(P)|=q|M:N_{G}(P)|\equiv q \mod p$, a contradiction.